# Can't insert data more than 254 in sqlite database by java

Tags: java, windows, sqlite, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am using a java class which allow me to insert data into SQLite database from string. I am inserting the data by a loop. My string have 260 data. When I try to insert those data from string to sqlite database it works fine but stops at the position of 254 every time! Why ?!

```
for(i = 0; i < 260; i++)
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\new.db");
            java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement .executeUpdate("INSERT INTO suggestion (suggesting) VALUES('"+words[i]+"')");
             System.out.println(i + " - " + words[i]);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Word.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Here is the error log from netbeans!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB$CausedSQLException.fillInStackTrace(NestedDB.java:442)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:250)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:54)
    at java.sql.SQLException.<init>(SQLException.java:140)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB$CausedSQLException.<init>(NestedDB.java:435)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB._open(NestedDB.java:63)
    at org.sqlite.DB.open(DB.java:77)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.<init>(Conn.java:88)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at test.Word.main(Word.java:106)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: are you sure that array is having valid values?

Comment: I cannot comment on the null-pointer other than to assume that the driver is refusing to create another connection because you keep creating connections and never close anyof them.. The code above is in serious need of re-factoring for use of prepared statements, a single connection and proper error checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running out of connections, because you are not closing them as required before opening a new one. Running out of connections shouldn't throw a `NullPointerException`; this seems to be a bug in sqlite.

A better and faster approach is: don't close the connection, but *don't open a new connection* every time.

You can do that like this:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Word.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\new.db");

for(i = 0; i < 260; i++)
{
    java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO suggestion (suggesting) VALUES('"+words[i]+"')");
    } finally {
        // Statements, like connections, also need to be closed after use
        statement.close();
    }
    System.out.println(i + " - " + words[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D
I have created so many connections by loop!
Now solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a re-factoring and update that might help.

I am assuming that the SQLite driver does not like the fact that you do not close your connections after using them (the actual `NullPointer` is probably a bug in the library you are using).

I also added the use of a `PreparedStatement` (which would be more efficient and less risky to SQL Injection attacks) as well as correct closing of resources (prior to Java 7 try-with-resources of course).

```
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement insert = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\new.db");
        insert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO suggestion (suggesting) VALUES(?)");
        for (String word : words) {                
            insert.setString(1, word);
            System.out.println("Word "+word+" inserted");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Word.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Driver not found", ex);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        Logger.getLogger(Word.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not execute SQL", sqle);
    } finally {
        if (insert != null) {
            try {
                insert.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                Logger.getLogger(Word.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not close prepared statement", sqle);
            }
            insert = null;
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                Logger.getLogger(Word.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not close connection", sqle);
            }
            connection = null;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.